# Как правильно настроить npm package.json?

Tags: node.js

Как правильно настроить npm package.json ? Правильно ли я это сделал, и какую функцию выполняют следующие разделы `"main": "index.js"` , `"devDependencies"` и `"scripts"` ?

---

```
{
  "name": "progectapi2", //Имя проекта
  "version": "1.0.0",    //Версия вашего проекта
  "description": "test", //Описание проекта
  "main": "index.js",    //Исходный файл npm, или чего именно? 
  "dependencies": {      //Зависимости для загрузки пакетов
    "sass": "^0.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}, // Точно не известно, вроде бы для публикации
  "scripts": {           // Какой то тест скриптов
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "My_Name",   //Имя автора
  "license": "UNLICENSED"//Лицензия
}
```

Comment: Я думаю [это](http://browsenpm.org/package.json) должно вам помочь.

Comment: А вы [документацию](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) читали? =)

Comment: Dmitriy Simushev - для меня там не все ясно.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Базовую настройку вы можете выполнить просто выполнив `npm init` в корне проекта. А `devDependencies` это dev зависимости проекта. Устанавливая что-то через npm вы можете воспользоваться флагом `--save-dev` и этот пакет будет записан в `devDependencies`, это полезно, чтобы другой человек разворачивая у себя проект мог с помощью команды `npm install` установить все нужные `devDependencies`.
`main` используется для возможности загрузки вашего package в виде `require("mainpackname")`
В `scripts` вы можете записать команды которые можно будет запускать через npm ваша команда. Пример `"start": "node app.js"` сделает доступной команду для вас `npm start`. Но лучше, хотя-бы раз вдумчиво прочитать документацию.